# Save JSON value as another JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file like below:

```
{
  "soils": [{
    "mukey": "658854",
    "mukeyName": "Meggett-Kenansville-Garcon-Eunola-Blanton-Bigbee (s1517)",
    "sl_source": "Fl soil map",
    "cokey": "3035468",
    "soilName": "Eunola",
    "comppct_r": 20,
    "compArea": "9.96",
  }],
  "asfirs": [{
    "long": -82.96896600817682,
    "lat": 29.977675992923395
  }],
  "polygon": [{
    "rings": [
      [
        [-9235836.910744485,
          3501136.0564117758
        ],
        [-9235798.692230342,
          3500237.921329426
        ],
        [-9236553.507884657,
          3500667.87961353
        ],
        [-9235836.910744485,
          3501136.0564117758
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "spatialReference": {
      "wkid": 102100,
      "latestWkid": 3857
    }
  }]
}
```

I want extract the value of Polygon key to another JSON object like below

```
{
  "rings": [
    [
      [-9161396.799823288,
        3453315.140590871
      ],
      [-9160708.866568722,
        3453095.3841345515
      ],
      [-9161349.02668061,
        3452751.4175072685
      ],
      [-9161396.799823288,
        3453315.140590871
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 102100,
    "latestWkid": 3857
  }
}
```

Now when I do it using

```
var key3 = 'polygon';
var newPolygonJSON = polygonJson[key3];
var text = JSON.stringify(newPolygonJSON);
```

where `polgonJson` contains my initial JSON file I get an extra `[]` bracket which is not allowing me to create a proper JSON file, like below.

```
 [{
   "rings": [
     [
       [-9235836.910744485,
         3501136.0564117758
       ],
       [-9235798.692230342,
         3500237.921329426
       ],
       [-9236553.507884657,
         3500667.87961353
       ],
       [-9235836.910744485,
         3501136.0564117758
       ]
     ]
   ],
   "spatialReference": {
     "wkid": 102100,
     "latestWkid": 3857
   }
 }]
```

How can I get rid of those `[]` brackets or extract the value properly?

Comment: @str. It is wrong. Variable `text` is of type string, so `text[0] === '['`.

Comment: True, it should be `newPolygonJSON[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you stringify JSON object, it puts extra `[]` brackets because it takes your object as an array. To extract JSON from `text` variable, you need to get value of the first (and only) element in that array.

```
var key3 = 'polygon';
var newPolygonJSON = polygonJson[key3];
var text = JSON.stringify(newPolygonJSON[0]);
```